# Hyperledger fabric web application

Tags: web-applications, hyperledger-fabric

How to build web applications for hyperledger fabric networks.I want to create a web UI for hyperledger fabric network using node.js.

Comment: Work hard by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am building one right now so perhaps i can help you with some pointers.

- Fabric supports Java,Node & Go SDK as of now so the first step would be to pick one
- Once done to interact with your front end you need to build an API client. I used go.
- Build a set of routers/servers to interact with your API to route requests.
- Build your config.yaml file in fabric to connect your API to hyperledger.
- Your config.yaml file is a very critical aspect in this part.
- Assuming the fabric network is up and running you are good to go.
- Test your app by running the main.go file (for my case).
- If your API is up and running, your CURL requests should go through.
- Finally its just a matter of calling your API from the front end.

Comment: How can I handle authentication in API? how should I define which user is calling API from the front?

Comment: My app has a login/registration page and isn't open for everyone, so users first must register themselves on the portal.  During registration they are marked as a part of a particular org. For example:- If a user is registers as an "importer" in the portal he gets tagged to "org-2: Traders" ; now when the registration is done , i have a custom API built that calls the fabric runtime, to create an user for him under that particular group and at the same time the enrollment is done by the Fabric-CA.

Comment: and where the enrollment keys store? on the. the server side?

Comment: I have a custom folder called crypto-config which holds all the network artifacts generated. The keys are stored in their respective org structure. Since the app is currently in development, we are storing them locally. Since we plan to deploy this solution on Azure cloud, i am thinking of using the "Azure Key Vault" service for storing it. But its not decided as of yet

Comment: @AurobindoNayak how did you generate the config.yaml file? I'm stuck in there

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric is a distributed Blockchain system and it comes with different ways to interact with consortiums

- sdk
- CLI

So Nodejs server-side SDK is available, all you have to do is set up a consortium and use fabcar Nodejs example in fabric-samples and try to leverage it with Nodejs template engines (handlebars js or pug ) or can use Reactjs in order to collect some data from users as a web application